# Is it possible to set rowHeight of slickgrid options by calling any function

Tags: slickgrid

I want variable **rowHeight** of the **slickgrid** depends on the no. of lines in content by calling any function.

```
this.getRowHeight = function(){
    return 45;
};

this.options = {    
    rowHeight: this.getRowHeight    
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row height is not adjustable per-row. This is built into the grid at a fundamental level.

Given that, if you just want to initially set `rowHeight` using your function, you want

```
this.getRowHeight = function(){
    return 45;
};

this.options = {    
    rowHeight: this.getRowHeight()   
};
```

That is, you want the *result* of the function, not the function itself. This is basic javascript, nothing to do with SlickGrid.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. It is working, but I want row height should depends on the content. Is it possible??

Comment: Sorry Anil, it's not possible with SlickGrid. The row height is used for calculations all through the core render code.